# ng add @angular/material fails with Command aborted

Tags: npm, installation, angular-material

Last summer, I updated all of my Angular/Node stuff to the latest, current, good versions:

```
Angular CLI: 12.0.5
Node: 14.17.1
Package Manager: npm 6.13.7
OS: win32 x64
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1200.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular   12.0.5
@angular-devkit/core            12.0.5
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.0.5
@schematics/angular             12.0.5
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.2.4
```

Today, when I started a new Angular project, I typed in

```
 ng add @angular/material
```

and got...

```
- Determining package manager...
i Using package manager: npm
- Searching for compatible package version...
√ Found compatible package version: @angular/material@12.2.12.
- Loading package information from registry...
√ Package information loaded.
Command aborted.
```

Any clues?